# What is the best way to make foreground service for real-time driver location update for ride hailing app in Android studio and kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building a ride-hailing app and I need a real-time driver location update even when the app is closed or in background, according to the new android os versions I can't use background services even if I could use it the os might kill it so my best option is to use foreground service with a noticeable notification, my question is, is it possible to use an ongoing foreground service for realtime location updates without being killed?

Answer (score 0):

A foreground service can still be killed, its just less likely to be so.  If the user was to open up a couple of memory hogging apps that meant it really needed your apps memory, it can still be killed.  There's a priority to what stays in memory, having a foreground service just makes it higher priority than an app with a background service using the same resources.  That said, a foreground service is your best bet for short duration updates like that.

Note that there's a difference between "closed" and backgrounded.  If the app is backgrounded, a foreground service will continue.  If the user terminates the app by swiping it away from recents or force stopping it, the foreground service will also be killed.  But the foreground service would allow him to move to another app (like Waze or something) without killing your app unless the phone goes really low on memory.

Comment: Ok, make sense but how do apps like Uber and Lyft get drivers locations in real-time without any issues?

Comment: They use a foreground service.  It just has a chance of failing.  They may also combine that with a backup service, like sending a high priority push message if they see that the stream of data from a driver that they expect to be sending data to wake them up again (which again will have a chance of failure).  Its one of those things where it doesn't need to be perfect, just good enough.

Comment: Ahaa, good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have a problem look like you . i am searching a lot and i test
foregroundservice , alarmManager , Worker and ...
none of them isnt working well and suddenly service stoped ! .
in the end i find 1 ways :
1- handle service in server in backened with pushNotificaiton .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great, can you give an example? It will be very helpful.